Vim: Different mappings to search with and without highlight
When I press g/ , it should search for word with the searched word left highlighted after pressing enter.
When I press /, it should search for word but not leave the searched word highlighted after pressing enter
This is the important aspect: In either case, the search should be highlighted until I have pressed enter.
I have this code to allow for the first requirement with / but I have no idea how to accomplish the second without affecting the first one.
-- Highlights searched pattern only until writing the search keyword
vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("vimrc_incsearch_highlight", { clear = true })
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("CmdlineEnter", {
  pattern = { "/", "\\?" },
  command = "set hlsearch",
  group = "vimrc_incsearch_highlight",
})
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("CmdlineLeave", {
  pattern = { "/", "\\?" },
  command = "set nohlsearch",
  group = "vimrc_incsearch_highlight",
})

Motivation: I use / to move around. I do want words to highlight while I am typing but not after I have reached there. But, I do not want to lose functionality to keep the search highlighted when required.
